# How to create a regular expression for Sitescope Log monitor logfile path?

Tags: regex, sitescope

we have a logfile with a path of

\servername\logs\e2serverd.20210107.000000.691088.log

What is the correct regex to match this logfile if the 12 numbers at the end are random?
I have tried

s/\servername\logs\e2serverd.$year$$0month$$0day$.000000.691088.log/ and it works but how do I express the full path so that it would match whatever the numbers at the end?

Answer (score 0):

checkout this link: https://regex101.com/r/bDfgU9/1

Whatever may be the 12 digits at the end before the words `.log`, it should match.(assuming that these 12 digits are seperated in 2 groups of 6 digits each)

Comment: Thanks. the regex works in that site but its not able to match the logfile I'm trying to read in Sitescope. Not sure if it is a SiteScope limitation.